# Localization online for description (iTunes Connect)

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store-connect

I have some descriptions in different languages I need in App Store.  The app does not need translation.

How do I do this in iTunes Connect when adding a new app?

I've been looking around for an hour but everything is about strings in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the Metadata and Uploads part you can choose different languages for your description.  It's confusing beucase you have to start getting your app ready for upload before you can enter the description.